# Mongodb Multiple $lookup and $unwind in same Aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hy I've two mongo DB collections, one for storing posts and another containing user details,

> here is the collection of my Users>>

```
{
  _id: objectId(1111111111),
  name: "userOne",
  email: userone@user.com
  picture: "link to profile picture"
},

{
  _id: objectId(2222222222),
  name: "userTwo",
  email: usertwo@user.com
  picture: "link to profile picture"
},

{
  _id: objectId(3333333333),
  name: "userThree",
  email: userthree@user.com
  picture: "link to profile picture"
}
```

> and here is the collection of Posts>>

```
{
  _id: objectId(44444444444),
  title : "Title of the Post",
  content: "Some Content",
  author: objectId(3333333333)
  likes: [
     0: {likeBy:objectId(1111111111),
         Date: "Date of Like"},

     1: {likeBy:objectId(2222222222),
         Date: "Date of Like"}
   ],
  comments: [
     0 : {user: objectId(1111111111),
          comment: "Nice",
          Date: "Date of comment" },

     1 : {user: objectId(2222222222),
          comment: "Good",
          Date: "Date of comment" }
   ]
}
```

so my aim is to fetch Author details, Liked user's details, commented user's details using MongoDB aggregation framework, How can do the same,
I already tried aggregation to do this but failed, Can anyone lead me to do this in a right way

> and this is my desired output

```
{
  _id: objectId(44444444444),
  title : "Title of the Post",
  content: "Some Content",
  author: {objectId(3333333333),
           name: "author's name from user collection",
           picture: "author's picture link form user collection" }
  likes: [
     0: {likeBy:objectId(1111111111),
         name: "user's name from user collection",
         picture: "user's picture link form user collection",
         Date: "Date of Like"},

     1: {likeBy:objectId(2222222222),
         name: "user's name from user collection",
         picture: "user's picture link form user collection",
         Date: "Date of Like"}
   ],
  comments: [
     0 : {user: objectId(1111111111),
          comment: "Nice",
          name: "user's name from user collection",
          picture: "user's picture link form user collection",
          Date: "Date of comment" },

     1 : {user: objectId(2222222222),
          comment: "Good",
          name: "user's name from user collection",
          picture: "user's picture link form user collection",
          Date: "Date of comment" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: can you share what you tried?

Comment: I extremely new to aggregation framework, so, I just tried $lookup to join user collection onto posts collection to retrieve user details, but I couldn't fully figure it out, I got the idea but Don't know to how to do the right way... @lovegupta

Comment: did you got solution..?have you tried something..?